# Travelling to UK as a non-EU citizen with permanent residence, together with my EU citizen spouse

Tags: visas, uk, eu, spouses

My spouse is Austrian citizen. I am not but I do have permanent residence in Austria. My nationality is Bosnian-Hercegovinian.

Can we travel together to UK for tourism purposes, without me needing a visa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the end of the Brexit transition period, the answer to this question is *no, you need a visa,* unless your spouse has resided in the UK since before the end of the transition period (23:00 UK time, December 31, 2020).  See https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/bosnia-and-herzegovina/tourism/yes